# How to write this SQL query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to write this query in laravel,

My table structures are

1. product table

> Product_Id    int(10)
>
> Product_Name  varchar(100)
>
> Product_Description   varchar(300)
>
> Category_ID   int(11)
>
> Brand_ID  int(11)

2.Stock_IN

> stock_ID  int(10)
>
> Product_ID    int(11)
>
> Product_Count int(11)
>
> Order_No   int(11)
>
> Supplier_ID   int(11)
>
> Order_date    text

3. stock_out

> stock_out_id  int(10)
>
> Product_ID    int(11)
>
> Product_Count int(11)
>
> Requisition_No int(11)
>
> Requisition_By    varchar(100)
>
> Recipient varchar(100)

My Query:

```
SELECT X.Product_ID,X.Product_Name,X.Count_StockIN,IFNULL(Y.Count_StockOut,0) Count_StockOut,(X.Count_StockIN-IFNULL(Y.Count_StockOut,0)) Balance FROM ( SELECT M.product_ID,M.Product_Name, SUM(Product_Count) AS Count_StockIN from (SELECT A.*,B.Product_Name FROM `stock_in` A, `products` B where A.Product_ID=B.Product_ID )M group by Product_ID,Product_Name ) X LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_ID, SUM(Product_Count) AS Count_StockOUT from `stock_Out`group by Product_ID ) Y On X.Product_ID=Y.Product_ID
```

The Output is:

[image]

How to write this query in laravel 4.2 . Please help me.

Comment: So... Are you using eloquent or query builder? Have you tried anything?

Comment: you can user query builder http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions ,with you can use count like count(1) to get group_by records count

Comment: I tried with query builder, but could't complete.

Comment: try http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins or http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#running-queries

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for your potential efforts. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **migration** to create table in laravel. And you can use **MODEL** to query into the corresponding table. Create a new migration to create table using following command on terminal inside your project root folder:

```
php artisan make:migration create_product_table --create="product"
```

You will get a new migration file in database/migration folder. And you will see a class with two methods: **up** and **down**. Up method is to create/modify table and down method is to rollback that table or action that you wrote in up method.
You can use following codes in up method:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('product_name',100);
            $tale->longText('product_description',300);
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('brand_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Similarly, you can create other table and you can modify existing table also. Then you should run the migrations using following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Please refer official documentation of [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) for more detail.

Comment: well explained answer!

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for your potential efforts. The problem is solved.